# How to use this.Html.DisplayFor to render a strongly-typed partial for poco object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

In views/home/index.aspx:

```
<% this.Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NewLink); %>
```

index.aspx is strongly typed to HomeViewModel.cs, which has the property used above right here:

```
public Link NewLink { get; private set; }
(in constructor), this.NewLink = new Link();
```

In views/home/displaytemplates/addform.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<urlme.Model.Link>" %>
this should show up on index.aspx
```

When I run it, nothing shows up at all.  I know that I can go a such a way that I create a separate view model for the partial to be bound to, then just name the partial view AddLinkViewModel.ascx, then it should work, but that's too much code and too long of a filename ;)  Do I need to use a UIHint?? Hopefully not, as that feels hack-ish.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot the = at the start of the tag so the display template is being parsed just not being written into the stream.

`<%=this.Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NewLink); %>`

Answer (score 0):

try naming the partial views/home/displaytemplates/link.ascx

Answer (score 0):

Try Html.DisplayForModel instead

```
<%= Html.DisplayForModel("addform", Model.NewLink) %>
```